# Merge tags networking and network-access?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I just came across the two tags [networking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) (x89) and [network-access](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-access) (x14). Checking the questions of the latter, I do not see what makes them as special as requiring this separate tag. So the question arises whether they should be merged and, optionally, synonymized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that they don't need to be distinct.  I've merged them into [networking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking).  A synonym wouldn't work since "network access" is a subset of "networking".

Comment: Ack. Hence the "optionally" in my request :) Thank you!